# Is there any Redis pub\sub benchmarks?

Tags: redis

I have found this [topic](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) benchmarking almost all the important Redis commands but it doesn't include PUB\SUB benchmarking. I would like to know something like how much time on average is consumed from the time a key gets created, deleted or expired and the notifications is received by the client for these event?

Also according to [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) in section (**Timing of expired events**) explaining that there could be a delay in the certain keys expired notifications if (1) I am not accessing these keys frequently, or (2) there are a lot of keys with TTL in the cache.

Answer (score 8):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/R09u__3Jzfk you can consider this discussion as benchmarking for Redis pub/sub. It's quite complicated to benchmark pub/sub as there are lot of metrics involved. No of publishers, subscribers, pattern subscribers everything does matters.

Regarding your second question, delay is because of point 2 alone. point 1 have nothing to do with the delay.